# Setup database replication between 2 servers

Tags: firewall, oracle, database-replication

Is it possible to setup replication of oracle databases, with one server outside the firewall? If so any suggestions on how to setup would be great.

Comment: You might get better answers on ServerFault.com

Comment: Do you need the entire DB shipped outside the firewall or would a select few views/tables suffice? Is it bi-directional or one-way (will the DB outside the FW be updateable)?

Answer (score 1):

We do log shipping. Basically, our primary is set to archive log mode, which creates the files, then every couple of hours, they get rsync'd (over ssh, so it's viable for your situation) to the backup where they get replayed.

This does mean that you can't query against the other server, because it's in standby mode, and you need to activate it, but the data is copied over.

You can read more about it in an answer that I posted to this question:

[Easy Oracle Log-Shipping](https://serverfault.com/questions/125720/easy-oracle-log-shipping/125781#125781)